# Dialogflow ES - I can't create Intent (only fallback intent)

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a trouble. I only see button in Dialogflow console "CREATE FALLBACK INTENT". And if I creating various intent , no one doesn't recognize users expressions and don't matching phrases. How I can solve this problem? [SCREENSHOT-CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOtcQ.png)

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution. I made a mistake, when creating an agent I turn toggle to on (mega agent). I don't know why, but mega agent can't create a regular intent, only fallback intent.  Ok, good luck to all, I think that this debugging (mistaking) will be useful to someone else!

Comment: You saved me a day of headache.. thanks man :)